# Django multiple file download

Tags: python, django, download

I am using FileWrapper to download a big file, but I don't know how to download multiple files in a single response. What other method can I use?

```
try:
    mms = message.objects.get(token=token)
except message.DoesNotExist:
    return HttpResponse('ret=1&msg=Invalid arguments&')

try:
    attach = mms.message_attach_set.get(id = int(attach_id))
except message_attach.DoesNotExist:
    return HttpResponse('ret=1&msg=Invalid arguments&')

response = HttpResponse(FileWrapper(attach.file), mimetype='application/force-download')
response['Content-Length'] = str(attach.file.size)
response['X-Sendfile'] = '%s' % (attach.realName)
return response
```

Comment: by the way, these files are splitted from multimedia. So when i download these files, i must to combine these files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be to create a `tarfile` archive and send the files as a single package
. The python api is [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html)